# link_to doesnt generate the right link, just appends to the current url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with generating a link with link_to.

Here is an example:

```
link_to 'foo/bar/baz', path
```

This does not give me desired link, but just appends the content of `path` to the current `url`

Example:

```
 url     :   www.example.com/home/foo
 path    :   home/foo/bar/baz
 link_to :   www.example.com/home/foo/home/foo/bar/baz
 desired :   www.example.com/home/foo/bar/baz
```

It just appends the `path` to the current `url`.

What am I doing wrong?

I tried with `self.send` and `eval` but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

All right the problem was that `path` has to have a leading `/` in front

It was

```
path    :   home/foo/bar/baz
```

but it has to be

```
path    :   /home/foo/bar/baz
```

else it is just appended to the `url`